# If $E[XY]=0$, then does that imply $E[X]=0$ or $E[Y]=0$?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, expected-value

I think that this is false, but I cannot think of a counterexample. Can anyone help?

EDIT: I am interested in the case when X,Y are not independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you are tossing a fair coin. Let $X=1$ if you get $H$ and $0$ if you get $T$.  Let $Y=1$ if you get $T$ and $0$ if you get $H$.

To be sure, if $X,Y$ are independent variables then $E[XY]=E[X]\times E[Y]$.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Expectation_of_product_of_random_variables).  That's enough to show what you want under the, strong, assumption of independence.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning it *is* true, however, under the assumption that $X,Y$ are independent. (This may have been why the OP couldn't find any counterexample.)

Comment: @ClementC.  Sure, I'll edit with a line to that effect.